# Jupyter magic sql for Db2 %%sql invalid syntax error while assigning a variable

Tags: jupyter-notebook, db2

I get invalid syntax error on =%%sql while trying to assign a variable to the %%sql. Can a variable to assigned ? I’m trying to bring the result in a dataframe.
For eg:
X=%%sql
Select id, name , address from employees
Where age>18

The same works when x=%sql select age from employees

Comment: What's your code? Share details.

Answer (score -1):

With details missing in your question, I would guess you want something like this:

```
%%sql myvariable <<
Select id, name , address from employees Where age>18
```

Look here under assignment: https://pypi.org/project/ipython-sql/